# Should we put a timer on server or mobile?

Tags: php, android, ios

I am working on both server side (beginning) and mobile side. There is an interesting thing but I am lack of experience to make a decision. I am appreciated any helps from you guys.

```
I have to send an email after 50 minutes
```

1/ If we have a timer for each email on server, then 1000 users, 1000 timers?

2/ If we handle it on mobile, there is a case that everything of the app is killed by OS before sending email.

The question is: server and mobile, which one is better?

Please let me know your solution. Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `queue` system on the server. Create a queue for sending emails.

When you want to send an email just push it in the queue, with time or DateTime in your case. Then run a `Cron Job` to check, process and send the email.

Also, make sure to implement the retry functionality, so that even email sending was failed the Cron will take the job again and try to send for a `number of times`.

These Links will Help:

[Managing Cron Jobs in PHP](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428)

[Setting Up Cron in Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-ubuntu-1804)

[Setting up Cron using cPanel](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cpanel/cpanel_cron_jobs.htm)

If you are confused about how to setup the Timings of Cron, checkout this website:

[CronTab Guru](https://crontab.guru/)

Comment: Let's say that failures need to be handled in some fashion. Whether an automatic retry is appropriate depends on requirements and the failure reason. Some failures you probably should NOT attempt retry.

Comment: @HarishST: Thank you for the quick reply. Can we make Cron Job it using PHP?

Comment: @SMor Yes, obviously. Retrying the failed cases always depends on some params as you mentioned. But in general you should always have to try and catch the errors and depends on the error received, you could try to send it again. Obviously, if the error is something that won't be recovered then there is no reason to try and send it again. That's why as a beginning stage I have included the `number of try` in my answer. If  even we are unable to caught the error, then the job should not be run after that `number of times`.

Comment: @LuongTruong Yes you can. You can set a Cron (Scheduler in Windows, I think) on your OS. If you are using cPanel then you can find the option to set Cron with the help of UI. If you are on Linux machine in general you can set the Cron. I will add the necessary reference to materials in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is better to implement the timer on your server. The negative possibility that would happen and block the function if you implement the timer on the device is when the device is on power-off mode or the device couldn't connect to the server to trigger for sending the email.

The server `instance` is should long-lived, this is should never go down, and this could be more reliable for your case, as @Harish ST answer, you can take a profit from cron job / cron task.